# How to perform a "$in" query with Waterline and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I am trying to do a "$in" query with waterline I have an Array and I want to get a list of document with ids that are in the array. I don't know how to do that.

I tried:

```
User.find()
.where({id : {in : array}})
done(...)
```

But it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Any way I can do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

ParticleBanana answered me here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sailsjs/dHxwsJvG5V8

I quote him here for convenience:

> When an array is passed in the where criteria an IN query will
>   automatically be run. So you can do the following:
>
> ```
> User.find().where({ id: [1,2,3] }).exec(function(err, users) { ... })`
> ```

It worked perfectly.